# Bootstrap HTML - Constrain Stack of Images to View

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a tough time figuring out how to do this.  I feel like I have multiple ideas, but I'm not sure what is proper or what to start with.

I'd like to keep the entire building in view based on the height of all the images together so all the images would resize equally to stay within the viewport.

Any help would be appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/J_Diddley/dvktj5df/

```css
.building {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="building">
  <div class="floor">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80" class="img-fluid img-floor">
  </div>
  <div class="floor">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80" class="img-fluid img-floor">
  </div>
  <div class="floor">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80" class="img-fluid img-floor">
  </div>
  <div class="floor">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80" class="img-fluid img-floor">
  </div>
  <div class="floor">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80" class="img-fluid img-floor">
  </div>
  <div class="floor">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80" class="img-fluid img-floor">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea... you have 6 floors, right? 100/6 = 16.6666. A floor is 120x80, i.e. 1.5 times as wide as it is tall. 16.6666 x 1.5 = 25. Math.

```
.floor{
  max-height: 16.66vh;
}
.floor img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 25vh;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dvktj5df/1/

Comment: That's super cool and works!  Thanks a ton!

Any ideas as how to manage it if the floors were different heights?

floor4 =  600 x 622;

floor3 = 600 x 220;

floor2 = 600 x 440;
 
floor1 = 600 x 336